# How to get the angle value of the base link of a floating based robot in Gazebo9

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

According to the api [gazebo 9.0 link](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/9.0.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Link.html#aa8607a26804719b0a11ca0b0dd8297d8).
for example ,I can get

```
this->model->GetLink("link1")->WorldPose();
this->model->GetLink("link1")->WorldLinearVel();
this->model->GetLink("link1")->WorldAngularVel();
this->model->GetLink("link1")->WorldLinearAccel();
```

But I can not find a way to get the angle value of the base link of a floating based robot like

```
this->model->GetLink("link1")->WorldAngular();
this->model->GetLink("link1")->WorldTwist();
```

Is there any suggestion? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19796/how-to-get-the-angle-value-of-the-base-link-of-a-floating-based--robot-in-gazebo9/) by [longwoo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3628/longwoo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 27 on 2018-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The WorldPose() function return ignition::math::Pose3d which consists of the position and orientation. You can get these like this:

```
ignition::math::Vector3 pos = this->model->GetLink("link1")->WorldPose()->Pos();

ignition::math::Quaternion rot = this->model->GetLink("link1")->WorldPose()->Rot();
```

Since the twist is a combination of angular_vel + linear_vel you just combine the WorldLinearVel() and WorldAngularVel() and you have it.

---

Originally posted by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) with karma: 350 on 2018-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [longwoo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3628/longwoo/) on 2018-06-26**:
Thank you. It works.